# How to launch Emacs for OS X in front of other applications

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On OS X, how do I start Cocoa emacs *and* bring it to front?](https://superuser.com/questions/73500/on-os-x-how-do-i-start-cocoa-emacs-and-bring-it-to-front)

I have [Emacs for OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/) installed on my MacBook Pro. In order to launch Emacs from the command line, I have created a file called `/usr/bin/emacs` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"
```

and I have chmoded the file to make it executable.

However, when I launch emacs from the command line, the emacs GUI window goes to the bottom of the UI stack and the terminal window stays on top. Is there any way I can get the emacs GUI to go to the top of the UI stack?

Answer (score 1):

You could add something like this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Emacs" to activate'
```

This will launch an AppleScript event that brings up the Emacs window, wherever it is.

Comment: Adding that line and commenting out the /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@" line worked but then the emacs window that launches does not open the file that I passed in as the argument to the emacs command on the command line.

Comment: Also...if I add that line without commenting out the /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@" line, then it just launches 2 sets of windows with the one containing the file I was trying to open still at the bottom of the UI stack.

Comment: Found the correct solution here - http://superuser.com/questions/73500/on-os-x-how-do-i-start-cocoa-emacs-and-bring-it-to-front

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Let's just close it then.